# What is the difference in Interrupted exception and IO Exception and how to use them(both)

Tags: bluej

While writing a program I faced this problem where since I used BufferedReader I required to throw IOException but also I needed to add a wait instance or a pause in the program in the snippet of which in all of them I found on the Internet there requires the throwing of Interruped Exception to which I am new. So I couldn't move forward. So is there a way to throw them both within the confinements of a single block? Also what is the difference between them? Also I am using BlueJ.

Comment: Why can't you just identify the method as throwing either type of exception?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you talking about moduling my program into separate blocks with separate methods? I cannot. I was given a base program and told to elevate it without increasing the number of methods used. That is the reason I specified it in the description that I cannot do so.

Comment: You are writing code within a method, a method which is tagged as (possibly) throwing an IOException.  Can't you just tag that method as also (possibly) throwing an InterruptedException?

Comment: Not actually. I tried so.

Comment: Can you post *how* you tried?  Maybe you did it wrong.